# (Android Studio) Par ou ímpar

Tags: java, android

Sou iniciante no Android Studio e preciso fazer um app que receba um número no EditText e depois me diga se ele é par ou ímpar, segue o meu código atual :
Não sei oq e onde colocar para quando apertar o botão (que já fiz) ter esse resultado... Help

```
public class exercicio1 extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tInforme;
EditText tValor;
Button btDescobrir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercicio1);

    tInforme = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tInforme);
    tValor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tValor);
    btDescobrir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDescobrir);}


        public void setbtDescobrir(View v) {
            String guessStr = tValor.getText().toString();
            int theGuess = Integer.parseInt(guessStr);

        }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o a operação `%` ela te volta o resto de uma divisão. No caso divida por 2  `%2`e se o resultado for 0 quer dizer que é par, se não é impar

editado:

```
String guessStr = tValor.getText().toString();
   int theGuess = Integer.parseInt(guessStr);
   int valor = theGuess%2;
   if(valor == 0){
      //imprima é par
   }
   else if(valor == 1){
    // imprima é impar
   }
```

Comment: Certo, mas onde exatamente coloco isso e como ? Eu tentei fazer isso e sempre dá erro, já que eu puxo o "btValor" (que é o id do EditText), no 'if' e ele não aceita o operador %. Obg

Comment: public void setbtDescobrir(View v) {
            String guessStr = tValor.getText().toString();
            int theGuess = Integer.parseInt(guessStr);
             return theGuess%2;
        }}

Comment: você deve pegar o valor que esta em int, no caso theGuess e verificar qual é o resto da divisão, pode tambem fazer um int valor = theGuess%2;
se valor for igual a 0 é par, se for igual a 1 é impar

Comment: não me lembro muito bem como funciona a estrutura de um android mas com certeza a logica que te passei está certa, if( valor == 0) { // imprima é par}else{//imprima é impar}

Comment: Ok, obg, vou tentar aqui

Comment: editei a resposta, acho que vai te ajudar mais

Comment: Consegui aqui, mto obg xD